# Swift 4 pass data between views

Tags: swift, request, parameter-passing

I have problem to pass my request from func to next view. I want to pass my request from VC1 to VC2  to send it to WkWebView.

VC1 contain this code:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: payURL!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let p = String(format: "TotalAmount=%@&Signature=%@&OrderID=%@&Version=%@&PurchaseTime=%@&TerminalID=%@&MerchantID=%@&Currency=%@&locale=%@&PurchaseDesc=%@",
                param["TotalAmount"]!    as! CVarArg,
                param["Signature"]!      as! CVarArg,
                param["OrderID"]!        as! CVarArg,
                param["Version"]!        as! CVarArg,
                param["PurchaseTime"]!   as! CVarArg,
                param["TerminalID"]!     as! CVarArg,
                param["MerchantID"]!     as! CVarArg,
                param["Currency"]!       as! CVarArg,
                param["locale"]!         as! CVarArg,
                param["PurchaseDesc"]!   as! CVarArg)

request.httpBody = p.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
let payController = kMainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EVPayControllerViewController") as! EVPayControllerViewController
payController.request = request
navigationController?.present(payController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

VC2

```
class EVPayControllerViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate {

    var request: URLRequest?
    let wkWebView = WKWebView()
    let webView = UIWebView()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(request?.httpBody)  //nil
    }
}
```

Comment: It is on main thread

Comment: Quick question: `request.httpBody` is not nil after you do `request.httpBody = p.data(...)` in VC1?

Comment: @Larme its not nil

Comment: Unrelated but you can replace the ugly `String(format` expression with `let p = param.map { (key, value) -> String in return "\(key)=\(value)" }.joined(separator: "&")` and `p.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)` with `Data(p.utf8)`

Comment: You don't just Segue?

Comment: Larme i want to navigate from func because i pass JSON params to this func

Comment: add didSet closure for `var request: URLRequest?`. If it will be invoked after you set it and didSet won't be called (e.g. it won't be set to nil somewhere, then I'd cleaned Xcode and deleted content of Derived Data folder)